# How to hide package structure for JavaScript target in multiplatform Kotlin project

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm building a library with Kotlin multiplatform, which should be used by native JVM and Node applications. I'm struggling to provide an idiomatic API for the Node version, because Kotlin [exposes the package structure to JavaScript](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/js-to-kotlin-interop.html#package-structure).

I'd like to have the definition of my entities in the common sourceSet within the package `com.company.myclientlib.common`:

```
// sourceSet: common
package com.company.myclientlib.common

data class Product(
    val id: String,
    val name: String,
    val displayName: String
    // ...
)
```

With this creating new `Product`s in a Node application looks like:

```js
// Node application code
const lib = require("lib")
const product = new lib.com.company.myclientlib.common.Product("id", "name", ...)
```

I've tried to put `@JsName("Product")` on the `Product` class. Although the name can be influcent with [`@JsName`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.js/-js-name/index.html), the package will still be exposed the same way.

**Is there any way to not to expose the package of `Product` in JavaScript without re-implementing the type in the JavaScript sourceSet of the library code?**

*Note*: Exposing the package for JVM targets is just fine.

Comment: Still nothing I bet...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for [JsQualifier](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.js/-js-qualifier/index.html)

Comment: JsQualifier works only with external so I'm not able to use it.